# Json get JsonArray from JsonArray

Tags: android, json, list

I have the following Json.  [link](http://myjson.com/124l0)

I would like to get `image_hall_list` and `image_place_list`  all `url` value.
I tried with the following code but no any result.

```
JSONObject JO = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray ja = JO.getJSONArray("image_place_list"); //get the array

 for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jo = null;
    try {
        jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);                    
        jsonurl.add(jo.getString("url"));
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```java
JSONObject JO = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray ja = JO.getJSONArray("place_list"); //get the array
for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jo = null;
    try {
        jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray imageHallList = jo.getJSONArray("image_hall_list");
        for (int j = 0; j < imageHallList.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject oneImageHallList = imageHallList.getJSONObject(j);
            jsonurl.add(oneImageHallList.getString("url"));
        }
        JSONArray imagePlaceList = jo.getJSONArray("image_place_list");
        for (int j = 0; j < imagePlaceList.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject oneImagePlaceList = imagePlaceList.getJSONObject(j);
            jsonurl.add(oneImagePlaceList.getString("url"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend some methods.

One to extract all the URLs for a given object.

```
public ArrayList<String> getURLs(JSONObject jo, String key) throws JSONException {
    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray arr = jo.getJSONArray(key);
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject innerObj = arr.getJSONObject(j);
        urls.add(innerObj.getString("url"));
    }
    return urls;
}
```

Then, you can use that twice for the respective keys. You also need to first get `"place_list"` based if your `result` variable is directly from that link.

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray ja = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("place_list"); //get the array

     for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);                    
        jsonurl.addAll(getURLs(jo, "image_hall_list"));
        jsonurl.addAll(getURLs(jo, "image_place_list"));
    }
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested for-loop. First grab the items before the `image_hall_list` and `image_place_list`, and then once you have the values stored, loop through `image_hall_list`, and `image_place_list` by getting that JSON object and loop through the elements in the JSON objects.